# Sharepoint Code Generation Tool

Tags: sharepoint, orm, sharepoint-2007, code-generation

our team is looking to use a code generation tool for the current sharepoint application we are working on. We want to be able to generate most of the stored procedures and business entities instead of having to write them from scratch. Any recommendation what is the best code generation tool to use with sharepoint projects. I am familiar with CodeSmith, but I wasn't sure if there are any better solutions out there for this.

Comment: Not sure if you've done a lot of SP development, but why would you be using stored procedures? (I assume you're speaking of using them to access content in the content DB, which is not supported by MS.)

Comment: Describe your application more in detail please and how you and your users plan on using it within a SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to talk to a custom database through a generated Data Access Layer, I would say go for the ADO.NET Entity Framework (works with VS2008 SP1 and .NET 3.5 SP1 only though. 
A custom solution would be [LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com)

Answer (score 3):

Code generation is not really necessary for SharePoint, all the code is generated in the SharePoint .NET Libraries.

The formulation of your question implies quite serious misunderstandings about SharePoint and it's use of databases.

Comment: I'm sorry may be my questions wasn't clear, but we need code generation for web parts that interact with an external database not the sharepoint one. I know the sharepoint database is only accessible through the sharpeoint libraries and we don't need code generation for that.

Comment: that does make more sense. Coding webpart can be a pain.

Comment: In that case I would suggest that your question has little to do with SharePoint (you are really talking about accessing a database from ASP.NET) and you might get better responses by removing the SharePoint tags and references.